# Touchscroll.js by davidaurelio - Alternative or fix

Tags: javascript, scroller

I was using touchscroll.js by davidaurelio but it doesn't work on ios at all.

Anyone can recomend me an alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: please mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To add momentum scroll to divs when viewed on ios devices add this to your container div CSS:

```
    overflow-y: scroll; /* has to be a scroll, not auto */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

[found here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements/)